# Java scoring method

Tags: java, string, loops

Currently stuck on a program to determine the highest score for a certain country. The problem I'm having is determining how to get the country with the highest score via input from the user. The main concern is outputting the country with the highest score and the medals it won with(ex USA wins 2 gold 1 silver 1 bronze). I'm only concerned with the American method atm. I put in some comments on areas I'm concerned with.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class OlympicMedalsEM
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int winner=0;
    String countrywin;
    int gold=0, silver=0, bronze=0, count=0, num=0, sum=0;      //num as in the number of countries
    int goldscore=0, silverscore=0, bronzescore=0;
    String country;
    {
    System.out.println("Please choose a scoring method. a for American or c for Canadian. ");
    char again = kb.next().charAt(0);
        if(again == 'a')//american method
        {
            // American method counts the medals with the most score. ex: gold is worth 3, silver 2, and bronze 1.
            // USA win 3 gold 1 silver 0 bronze = 11 points so to speak.
            {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of countries competing: ");
            num = kb.nextInt();
            {
            for (int x=0; x < num; x++)
                {
                System.out.println("Enter country and medal count(from gold to bronze): ");
                country = kb.next();
                gold = kb.nextInt();
                silver = kb.nextInt();
                bronze = kb.nextInt();
                country += country; // not sure if for loops works better than while. Not even sure is country should be counted
                }
            }
                    {
                    goldscore = gold * 3;
                    silverscore = silver * 2;
                    bronzescore = bronze * 1;
                    sum = goldscore + silverscore + bronzescore;
                        winner = sum;
                        // determine the highest score for the winner(?)
                        if (sum < winner) 
                    winner = sum;
                    }
                {
                // country is String need to change to a int(?). 
                // need it to also figure out how to pick the country with the high quality of medals
                // Possibly substitute countrywin instead of country?
                    System.out.println("The winner is: " + country + " with " + gold + " gold medals," + silver + " silver medals, and " + bronze + " bronze medals.");
                }
            }
        }
        else if(again == 'c')//canadian method
        {
            // Canadian method which counts the total number of medals
            {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of countries competing: ");
            num = kb.nextInt();
            {
            while (count<=num)
                {
                System.out.println("Enter country and medal count(from gold to bronze): ");
                country = kb.next();
                gold = kb.nextInt();
                silver = kb.nextInt();
                bronze = kb.nextInt();
                // need to understand the american version first before proceding
                +=;
                }
            }
                    {
                    sum = gold + silver + bronze;
                        }
                {
                    System.out.println("The winner is: " + country + " with " + gold + " gold medals," + silver + " silver medals, and " + bronze + " bronze medals.");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.err.println("invalid answer");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If this is homework, it should probably be tagged with the 'homework' tag.

Comment: it says that the homework tag is going to be taken away. Not sure if i should add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it like this. If an country's medal count input is less than the previous one, why continue to store it. Have a variable for the current high, and only overwrite them if needed.

```
int currentHigh = 0;
int noOfCountries = 10;
int input;

for(int i=0; i<noOfCountries; i++) {
    input = in.nextInt();
    if(input>currentHigh) {
        currentHigh=input;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, that actually makes more sense. But for noOFCountries, is that for a predetermined number of countries or can it be used for what ever number the user inputs?

Comment: @Plank_Boy: I only have that there as an example. You can take another user input to change that by just doing `int noOfCountries=in.nextInt()`

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Priority Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)
You can get the min/max you need by using your own [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Answer (score 0):

If this is homework, have you learned about classes yet? This looks like a very good time to use them.

I would make a countries class that has fields for each medal count and country name. You could then write a sum method in the class that would return the value of all the medals that country has. Then check the sum of the current Country to the country that has the highest score with something similar to @pattmorters answer.

Also, I would swap your `if/else` statements for a `switch`. (Pretty much made for menu selection).

If this isn't homework I can give you some sample code. ;)

Comment: I'm afraid we haven't covered that much on classes. I think that's next weeks subject. As for pattmorter's answer, it might be what would work for the program. Only tricky part is outputting country as a String when other outputs are int.

Comment: Well your, `country += country` might not be what you expect. You need to find a way to map the info together. You could use an array for each item. Using this you would know that if `sum[1] > sum[2]` than `country[1]` is currently the winner. Does that make Sense?

Java string concatenation will handle outputting the mixed strings and int values without you having to worry.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use arrays to store sum values and countrys' names. for your situation you can use the code. its not necessarily perfect but it works. you can also add try and catch blocks to ensure the program does not crash when the user inputs wrong type of data i.e. int instead of char.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 class OlympicMedalsEM
  {
    public static void main (String[] args)
      {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int goldscore=0, silverscore=0, bronzescore=0;
        String[] country;
       {
         System.out.println("Please choose a scoring method. a for American or c for Canadian.");                              
char again = kb.next().charAt(0);
    if(again == 'a')//american method
    {
        // American method counts the medals with the most score. ex: gold is worth 3,    silver 2, and bronze 1.
        // USA win 3 gold 1 silver 0 bronze = 11 points so to speak.
        {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of countries competing: ");
        int num = kb.nextInt();
        int []sum = new int[num];            // Create sum array with "num"         number of elements, each representing sum for one country
        country = new String[num];           
        {
        /** each country is saved in a string array "country" element with corresponding sum in the "sum" array */
        for (int x=0; x < num; x++)
            {
            System.out.println("Enter country and medal count(from gold to bronze): ");
            country[x] = kb.next();
            goldscore = kb.nextInt()*3;
            silverscore = kb.nextInt()*2;
            bronzescore = kb.nextInt()*1;
            sum[x]= goldscore+silverscore+bronzescore;

            }
        }       /** gets index of array "sum" with highest value element */
                int MaxIndex=0;
                for (int c=0; c<sum.length-1; c++){
                   if (sum[c+1]>sum[c]){
                   MaxIndex=c+1;
                   }
                }
                /** country with most medals is saved in the same index number as the maximum sum index */
                System.out.println(" the country with most medals is :" + country[MaxIndex]);
                }
                }

                }
                }
                }
```